# Using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to create a session?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, jpa

I am using `Spring` for the first time. Is it possible to use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` in order to create something similar to a hibernate session?

I am familiar with creating a hibernate session from `hibernate.cfg.xml` and also from `entityManagerFactory` in JPA.

But how do I use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` in order to be able to carry out transactions against my database?

Comment: Do you want to create `SessionFactory` or `EntityManagerFactory`?

Comment: @v.ladynev He wants to create EntityManagerFactory as LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is FactoryBean that creates a JPA EntityManagerFactory

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera Ok.Thanx.

Comment: thanks @PragnaniKinnera that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to define jpa transaction manager which will be configured to your LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, for example :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>



<bean id="entityManagerFactory"

        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="enginePU" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
           <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_catalog">ab</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
      </bean>
```

then if you configured the transaction to be annotation driven :

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

you can use the entityManager in your daos like this :

```
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;


    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void persist(Object o) throws IOException {
         entityManager.persist(o);
    }
```

Hope it helps.